# How to move list of files to some directory

Tags: java, java-8, java-7

I want to move list of files in one directory to other directory. I could see code to move single file to another directory. But I want to move all files in one directory to another directory in efficient way, because i need to move bulk files.

Tried Below code:

```
        Path temp = Files.move
        (Paths.get("C:\\******\\Test\\1.txt"),  
        Paths.get("C:\\********\\Test\\Archieve\\1.txt")); 

        if(temp != null) 
        { 
            System.out.println("File renamed and moved successfully"); 
        } 
        else
        { 
            System.out.println("Failed to move the file"); 
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? What have you tried and what is the problems should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code :

before proceeding to code we have to import appropriate java packages.Like this :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.*;
```

Now we move to coding part, at first we have to specify the path of the folder from which we are going to move the files to do that :

```
String str_source = "D:\\temp";
```

Then We are going to specify the path of the folder in which we are going to move the files. To do that :

```
String str_target = "D:\\temp1\\";
```

Then We are listing out all the files from the original folder. To do this :
1. have to pass original folder name to the file object.
2. get list of files into the file array from the folder using that object.

```
File directory = new File(str_source);
File[] filesList = directory.listFiles();
```

Then we have to move files from one folder to the another folder.

```
Path result = null;
try
{
    for(File file:filesList)
    {
        result = Files.move(Paths.get(file.getPath().toString()), Paths.get(str_target+file.getName().toString()));
    }
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("Exception while moving file: " + e.getMessage());
}
if(result != null) 
{
    System.out.println("File moved successfully.");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("File movement failed.");
}
```

Entire Code look like :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.*;
public class filemovetest {
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      String str_source = "D:\\temp";
      String str_target = "D:\\temp1\\";
      File directory = new File(str_source);
      File[] filesList = directory.listFiles();

      for(File file:filesList)
      {
          System.out.println(file.getPath());
      }

      Path result = null;
      try 
      {
         for(File file:filesList)
         {
             result = Files.move(Paths.get(file.getPath().toString()), Paths.get(str_target+file.getName().toString()));
         }
      } 
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
         System.out.println("Exception while moving file: " + e.getMessage());
      }
      if(result != null) 
      {
         System.out.println("File moved successfully.");
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("File movement failed.");
      }  
   }

}
```

Hope This will help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();    // --> Get names of all the files in your folder

listOfFiles.forEach((file) ->  {        // --> Iterate through the filenames and move
Path moveFile = Files.move(Paths.get("C:\\OldFilePath\\"+file.getName()),Paths.get("C:\\NewFilePath\\"+file.getName()))

if(fileMove != null)     // --> Verify that the file is moved successfully
   { 
      System.out.println("File moved successfully"); 
   } 
   else
   { 
      System.out.println("Failed to move the file"); 
   } 
});
```